# Shell script to extract a filename from log message lines

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I have txt file which listed with some line. Each line has image names included. What I want is, The shell script that edit same txt file OR copy particular image name to new file.

This is my txt file having list of images with their paths.
[image]

And I want output like this:

[image]

I want only image names should be extract from those lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `awk`,

```
awk '{ split($1,arr,"/"); print arr[length(arr)] }' yourfile > output.txt
```

Comment: @iMash, I don't know why. Next-time, Please post the question with **your efforts or what you have tried so far** to solve. It may avoid the down vote. Now, I am giving +1.

Answer (score 1):

Using `gnu sed` you can do:

```
sed -r 's~^[^[:blank:]]*/([^/ ]+) .*$~\1~' file
1.png
1@2x.png
2.png
2@2x.png
3.png
```

Comment: How do I Execute this through terminal?

Comment: Just type this command in shell: `sed -r 's~^[^[:blank:]]*/([^/ ]+) .*$~\1~' file`

Comment: iMac:desktop MashMac$ sed -r 's~^[^[:blank:]]*/([^/ ]+) .*$~\1~' templist.txt 

This is how I execute in terminal 'templsit.text' is my file name..but it gives following error.

sed: illegal option -- r
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]

Comment: OSX does not have GNU sed so the option names are slightly different. Try `-E` instead of `-r`.

Comment: It works great Just wanted to take all those name in new file. For now its giving list there itself.

Comment: @iMash: For inline editing of file you can do: `sed -i.bak -E 's~^[^[:blank:]]*/([^/ ]+) .*$~\1~' f`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
cat the_file.txt|while read file; do
    echo $(basename $file)
done
```

And (if needed) redirect the output on another file.

Answer (score 0):

```
while read fn rest
do
    basename "$fn"
done < file.txt
```

This will read your input line by line. It will put the filename (including path) into the `fn` variable, and whatever is on the rest of the line into `rest`. Then it uses the `basename` command to strip off the path and just print out the filename itself.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. When posting code, please also try to explain it, so that the OP can understand it.

Answer (score 0):

This is another `sed` solution that doesn't use extended regular expression (more portable solution):

```
sed 's/^.*\/\([^[:blank:]\/]*\)[[:blank:]].*$/\1/' sourceFile > destFile
```

You have to replace `sourceFile` and `destFile` white the path to oridinal and destination file respectively.

The command look for any string without blank char or slashes `\([^[:blank:]\/]*\)` preceeded by a slash `^.*\/` and followed by a blank char `[[:blank:]].*$` than the patter is substitituded with the first matching string `/\1/`.

You could read a quick `sed` reference [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html).